# Cannot Access S3 resources with CORS configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, mapbox

Good day,

I am using the following tutorial to create an S3 bucket to store a .csv file that is updated hourly from google drive via a Lambda routine:

https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/sheetmapper-advanced/#cors-configuration

When I try to access the .csv from its S3 object URL by inserting it into the browser

https://mapbox-sheet-mapper-advanced-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/SF+Food+Banks.csv

I get the following error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y795M.png)

The CORS permission given in the tutorial is in XML format:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have tried to convert it into JSON format, as it seems the S3 console no longer supports CORS permissions in XML format:

```js
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have you account permissions able to support public access to S3. There are four things that I ran into today while trying to make a public S3 resource.

1. Account settings for block public access has to be disabled. (MAKE SURE TO ENABLE IT FOR ANY PRIVATE BUCKETS OR OBJECTS)
2. Individual block public access has to be disabled. (As shown in your tutorial)
3. ACL must allow read access. You can find this under S3 - Buckets - your_bucket - permissions - Access Control list. Edit this for read access.
4. Go to the individual object and ensure that it also has permissions to be read from the public.

Comment: It seems points #3 and/or #4 (made both changes before testing) have solved the problem.

Much appreciated Jordan!